# NullPointerException while creating new Persistent Manager in Datanucleus

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

In Application which uses datanucleus for JDO we getting following exception :
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextPool.checkOut(ExecutionContextPool.java:97)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.getExecutionContext(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:1130)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.(JDOPersistenceManager.java:143)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.newPM(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:853)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:832)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:813)

My code is :

```
public class OrderRequestQueueProcessor implements Processor {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(OrderRequestQueueProcessor.class);

private OrderServiceImpl orderService;
private PersistenceManagerFactory pmf;
private ProvisioningErrorMessageServiceImpl provisioningErrorMessageService;
private NotificationServiceImpl notificationService;
private OrderLineService orderLineService;

@Override
public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    logger.debug("started");
    PersistenceManager persistenceManager = null;
    Message messageIn = null;
    Order order = new Order();
    OrderRequestQueueProcessorAE orderRequestQueueProcessorAE = null;

    try {
        persistenceManager = this.pmf.getPersistenceManager();
        messageIn = exchange.getIn();
        logger.trace("pm in processor:" + persistenceManager);
        String orderQueueProcessorStr = String.valueOf(messageIn.getBody());
        logger.debug("orderQueueProcessorStr="+orderQueueProcessorStr);
        orderRequestQueueProcessorAE = new ObjectXMLConverter<OrderRequestQueueProcessorAE>()
                .convertXMLtoObject(
                        OrderRequestQueueProcessorAE.class,
                        orderQueueProcessorStr,
                        Boolean.valueOf(DBProperties
                                .getProperties(ProvisioningDBConstants.IS_COMPRESS)));
        String channelid = orderRequestQueueProcessorAE.getChannelid();
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("initcorrelationid of OrderRequestQueueProcessor::"
                    + orderRequestQueueProcessorAE.getInitcorrelationid());
        }
        /* MSISDN: It can be 9-12 digit in length */
        String regex = DBProperties
                .getProperties(ProvisioningDBConstants.MSISDN_REGEX);
        String msisdnForRequest = orderRequestQueueProcessorAE.getMsisdn();
        if (null != msisdnForRequest) {
            if (!(msisdnForRequest.matches(regex))) {
                throw new ProvisioningValidationException(
                        ProvisioningExceptionConstants.INVALID_MSISDN_FORMAT);
            }
        } else {
            throw new ProvisioningValidationException(
                    ProvisioningExceptionConstants.ENTER_MSISDN);
        }
        // convert MSISDN to 9 digit
        String msisdn = this.convertTolength(msisdnForRequest);
        orderRequestQueueProcessorAE.setMsisdn(msisdn);
        // validate request parameter(username,password,msisdn)
        this.validate(orderRequestQueueProcessorAE, persistenceManager);

        // create Order Number for future reference
        // generate a new order
        // create Order without subscription type and opco
        order = this.orderService.createOrderNumber(messageIn.getHeaders(),
                persistenceManager, orderRequestQueueProcessorAE);

        orderRequestQueueProcessorAE
                .setErrorResponseXmlResourcePath("/errorResponse.xml");

        // If request is from Schedular validate InstalledBase parameter in
        // exchange
        if (channelid
                .equalsIgnoreCase(DBProperties
                        .getProperties(ProvisioningDBConstants.CHANNEL_SCHEDULER_CODE))) {
            if (null != messageIn
                    .getHeader(ProvisioningDBConstants.INSTALLED_BASE_ID)) {
                long installedbaseid = exchange.getIn().getHeader(
                        ProvisioningDBConstants.INSTALLED_BASE_ID,
                        Long.class);
                orderRequestQueueProcessorAE
                        .setInstalledbaseid(installedbaseid);
            } else {
                logger.error("installedbaseid not found");
                throw new ProvisioningEngineException(
                        ProvisioningExceptionConstants.INSTALLED_BASE_ID_NOT_FOUND);
            }
        }
        orderLineService.process(orderRequestQueueProcessorAE, exchange,
                persistenceManager, order);

    } catch (final ProvisioningValidationException ve) {
        logger.error("Error in OrderRequestQueueProcessor\t", ve);
        validationFailureNotification(orderRequestQueueProcessorAE,
                persistenceManager, ve, exchange);
    } catch (final ProvisioningException de) {
        logger.error("Error in OrderRequestQueueProcessor\t", de);
        orderService.updateFailureOrder(order, exchange, de.getMessage(),
                orderRequestQueueProcessorAE, persistenceManager);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error in OrderRequestQueueProcessor\t", e);
        orderService.updateFailureOrder(order, exchange,
                ProvisioningExceptionConstants.GENERIC_ERROR_MSG,
                orderRequestQueueProcessorAE, persistenceManager);

    } finally {
        if (persistenceManager != null) {

            persistenceManager.close();
        }
    }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    logger.debug("Time Take(MillSeconds):" + (endTime - startTime));
    logger.debug("finished");
}
```

I am using datanucleus version 4.0.0-release.
And we dont get and db error codes. Please help

Comment: and why don't you post YOUR code, and your PMF code, and what versions of things you're using

Comment: added code. PMF is injected using spring .

Comment: so use something more recent perhaps